# How to include different view in the same html page with framework7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I'm a beginner with framework 7. I'm developing a little app and I split the html code in different files because i have a lot of pages with div in common. My problem is: I have a page.html, inside my page.html I'd like to include different div in the same windows from different html files.
for example in php we can do it with a

```
include("");
```

but in framework7  I can include only one with

```
<div class="view view-main view-init" data-url="/page/" data-name="page"></div>
```

I'd like to include more one view like this

```
<div class="view view-main view-init" data-url="/page1/" data-name="page1"></div>
<div class="view view-main view-init" data-url="/page2/" data-name="page2"></div>
```

i put an image here to explain me better.

[what i'd like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A3Oq.jpg)
Thank you for your help.

pages.html

```
<div data-name="pages" class="page">    
<div class="page-content pg-no-padding">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-100 tablet-100 desktop-80">
            <div class="block">
            <form class="list" id="pages1">

                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="block-title">
                        <h1> Pages</h1>
                    </div> <!--block-title-->
                </div><!--row-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="block-title">
                            <h2> Card 1</h2>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-content card-content-padding"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
                                    <div class="list no-hairlines-md">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="item-content item-input">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <div class="item-title item-label">Input1</div>
                                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                                    <input type="number" placeholder="" name="">
                                                    <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="item-content item-input">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <div class="item-title item-label">Input2</div>
                                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                                    <input type="number" placeholder="" name="">
                                                    <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--col-->
                            </div><!--row-->
                            </div><!--card-content-->
                        </div><!--card-->                               
                    </div><!--col-->
                </div><!--row-->


                Here I'd like to include the code inside pages1.html

                Here I'd like to include the code inside pages2.html


            </form> 
            </div><!--block-->


            <div class="block">
            <a class="col button button-fill" href="#">Salva</a>
            </div>

        </div><!--col-100-->        
    </div><!--row-->
</div> <!-- ./ page-content-->
```

pages1.html

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="block-title">
                            <h2> Card2</h2>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-content card-content-padding"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
                                    <div class="list no-hairlines-md">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="item-content item-input">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <div class="item-title item-label">Input1</div>
                                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                                    <input type="number" placeholder="" name="">
                                                    <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="item-content item-input">
                                            <div class="item-inner">
                                                <div class="item-title item-label">Input2</div>
                                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                                    <input type="number" placeholder="" name="">
                                                    <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--col-->
                            </div><!--row-->
                            </div><!--card-content-->
                        </div><!--card-->                               
                    </div><!--col-->
                </div><!--row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

To include Multiple Views Layout you need to do this:

1. You need to create wrapper with class views like this: `<div class="views tabs">`
2. You need to create div view like this: `<div class="view view-main tab tab-active" id="view-1">.related page..</div><div class="view tab" id="view-2">.related page..</div>`
3. You need to make sure thats only one views class wrapper.

In Js: You can control multiple views by this:

```
var view1 = app.views.create('#view-1', {...}); 
var view2 = app.views.create('#view-2', {...});
```

For more details: [F7 View](https://framework7.io/docs/view.html)

For Embedded Multi view not like tab: 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5prjqm34/1/)
Note: for each view in F7 is got 100% height...you need to make sure thats height is equal 100% finally

Comment: Hi Anees, thank you for your help, but it creates tab. I edited my questions to explain me better.

Comment: Your welcome mate...I updated my answer by adding now a real example for multi view like your image...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I saw the example, but the content MainView in my case is inside page1.html and  the content homeview inside page2.html

Comment: Welcome fgg, you need to set routes for view1 and view2...thats load needed content as you like for example: routes: [// First one
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './home.html'
  },
]
// Second one: 
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './page2.html'
  },
]

I think this will resolve you issue

Comment: I included the path in my-app.json but How can I include pages1.html and pages2.html in pages.html? i uploaded my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After a long investigation, I found from the documentation that you can do it like this:

```
<!-- in your views page, just add these parameter to your view you want to inherit -->
<div class="view view-init" data-url="/your-page/" data-name="home" data-push-state="true">
  ...
</div>
```

And in your routers, will need to define your route as well:

```
var app = new Framework7({
  root: '#app',

  // Create routes for all pages
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      url: 'index.html',
    },{
      // Add your contents page route 
      path: '/your-page/',
      url: 'pages/your-page.html',
    },
    .....
});
```

Hope this help.